# Deleting row in jQuery Datatable Not Working

Tags: jquery, datatables

Not sure about the use of the get to get dom element here, any suggestions?

```
selected_received_id = $(this).parents('tr').data('id');
row_element = $(this).parents('tr');
received_table.fnDeleteRow(row_element.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var nRow =  $(tableid + ' tbody tr[id='+ rowid +']');

if (nRow.length > 0)
{
    var oTable = $(tableid).dataTable();
    oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow[0],null,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
selected_received_id = $(this).parents('tr').data('id');
var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(row_element);
if (iPos !== null) {
    oTable.fnDeleteRow(iPos);//delete row
}
```

or this:

```
$(".datatable tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function () {
    var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
    if (iPos !== null) {
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(iPos);//delete row
    }
});
```